# Vue CLI + Tailwind: Theming with CSS Variables

Tags: tailwind-css, vue-cli, css-variables, theming

The setup below works as expected on:

```
yarn serve
```

However it **does not add** the custom theme varaiables to the **generated CSS** file on:

```
yarn build
```

### Setup:

**project\src\assets\tailwind.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@layer components { [...] }
@layer base {
  :root{
   --color-text-title: 0, 0, 0;
   [...]
  }
  .theme-customOne{
   --color-text-title: 0, 255, 0;
   [...]
   }
  .theme-customTwo{
   --color-text-title: 0, 0, 255;
   [...]
   }
}
```

**project\tailwind.config.js**

```
  function withOpacity(variableName) {
    [...]
  }

  module.exports = {
    purge: { content: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.vue"] },
    darkMode: false,
    theme: {
     extend: {
      textColor: {
        skin: {
          title: withOpacity("--color-text-title"),
          [...]
        }
      }
     }
   }
  }
```

### Output:

**project\dist\css\index.cae56bc4.css**

```
 :root{
  --color-text-title: 0, 0, 0;
  [...]
 }
```

Is there a way to get the theme specific **CSS Variables** in the generated CSS file as part of the build process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figurd it out by myself.
The solution is to add the custom classes you would like to preserve to your tailwind.config.js like so:

```
module.exports = {
 purge: {
  content: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.vue"],
  safelist: ["theme-customeOne", "theme-customTwo"]
},
[...]
}
```

After that you can run:

```
yarn build
```

If you now check the generated CSS e.g. **project\dist\css\index.cae56bc4.css**
you will find the custom class + custom CSS variables inside that file.

I share my solution in case it might be helpful to anyone else who will come across
this issue.